# How do I save the changes to my image after each step?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a photo editing web application and whenever I make one change to my image the other one disappears. For example, if I rotate my image then the flip is not working correctly. It's flipping the original image only. I probably need to save my image after each change. How do I go about doing that?

Here's my HTML:

```
<p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
<p><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;" id="fileBtn">Upload Image</label></p>
<p><img id="img" /></p>

<!-- side nav -->
<div class="sidenav">
    <label for="filter-select">FILTER AND ADJUST</label>
    <div class="slider">
        <p style="color: aliceblue;">Sepia</p>
        <input id="sepia" type="range" oninput="setSepia(this);" value="0" step="0.1" min="0" max="1"><span id="Amount" style="color: white;"> (0)</span><br/><br>

        <p style="color: aliceblue;">Grayscale</p>
        <input id="Grayscale" type="range" oninput="setGs(this);" value="0" step="0.1" min="0" max="1"><span id="Amount2" style="color: white;"> (0)</span><br/><br>
    </div>
    <label onclick = "RotateImg()">ROTATE</label>
    <label onclick = "flipping()">FLIP</label>
</div>
```

And here's my Javascript:

```
function loadFile(event) {
    var image = document.getElementById('img');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}

function setSepia(e){
    document.getElementById('img').style["webkitFilter"] = "sepia("+e.value+")";
    document.getElementById('Amount').innerHTML="("+e.value+")";
}

function setGs(e){
    document.getElementById('img').style["webkitFilter"] = "grayscale("+e.value+")";
    document.getElementById('Amount2').innerHTML="("+e.value+")";
}

let rotation = 0;
function RotateImg(){
    rotation += 90;
    if (rotation == 360) {
        rotation = 0;
    }
    document.querySelector("img").style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`;
}

let scale = 1
function flipping() {
    scale -= 2
    if (scale <= -2) {
        scale = 1;
    }
    document.querySelector('img').style.transform = `scaleX(${scale})`;
}
```

Comment: You will see you are applying code to the `img` tag every time not on the changed or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store all the options in an object and after they update apply them all it should work.

I Have updated all the required methods below:

```js
function loadFile(event) {
  var image = document.getElementById("img");
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}

const options = {
  sepia: 0,
  grayscale: 0,
  rotation: 0,
  scale: 1,
};

function setSepia(e) {
  options.sepia = e.value;
  document.getElementById("Amount").innerHTML = "(" + e.value + ")";
  redraw();
}

function setGs(e) {
  options.grayscale = e.value;
  document.getElementById("Amount2").innerHTML = "(" + e.value + ")";
  redraw();
}

let rotation = 0;

function RotateImg() {
  rotation += 90;
  if (rotation == 360) {
    rotation = 0;
  }
  options.rotation = rotation;
  redraw();
}

let scale = 1;

function flipping() {
  scale -= 2;
  if (scale <= -2) {
    scale = 1;
  }
  options.scale = scale;
  redraw();
}

function redraw() {
  document.getElementById("img").style["webkitFilter"] =
    "sepia(" + options.sepia + ") grayscale(" + options.grayscale + ")";
  document.querySelector(
    "img"
  ).style.transform = `rotate(${options.rotation}deg) scaleX(${options.scale})`;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
<p><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;" id="fileBtn">Upload Image</label></p>
<p><img id="img" src="https://wallpapersdsc.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Charleston-Images.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px" /></p>

<!-- side nav -->
<div class="sidenav">
  <label for="filter-select">FILTER AND ADJUST</label>
  <div class="slider">
    <p style="color: aliceblue;">Sepia</p>
    <input id="sepia" type="range" oninput="setSepia(this);" value="0" step="0.1" min="0" max="1"><span id="Amount" style="color: white;"> (0)</span><br/><br>

    <p style="color: aliceblue;">Grayscale</p>
    <input id="Grayscale" type="range" oninput="setGs(this);" value="0" step="0.1" min="0" max="1"><span id="Amount2" style="color: white;"> (0)</span><br/><br>
  </div>
  <label onclick="RotateImg()">ROTATE</label>
  <label onclick="flipping()">FLIP</label>
</div>
```

*Edit: to clarify why the values are reset is because you override the old value whenever you change one of the properties with a new value.*

Comment: Thank you this works fine but when we upload our image and we use the filter or rotate feature the image disappears and it doesn't appear until we click on flip. However, after that, the changes work fine. Any idea, how we can solve this issue?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a small fix. The options.scale was set to 0 instead of 1. This change should fix the problem